# Can an STL vector be "reset" so that it reuses the same memory if possible?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Often, in simulations, I find that I need to have a potentially large vector that gets completely rewritten from iteration to iteration, but is not exactly the same size each time.  I do not want to reallocate the memory every time but I also do not know the exact size in advance.

Essentially, I want this kind of behavior:

```
struct reusable_vec{
    std::vector<int> v;
    int actual_size;
    reusable_vec(){actual_size=0;}
    void push_back(int val){
        if (v.size() < actual_size){
            v.push_back(val);
        } else {
            v[actual_size]=val;
        }
        actual_size++;
    }
    int &operator[](int index){
        if (index < actual_size){
            return v[index];
        } else {
          throw invalid_argument("I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.");
        }
    }
    void reset(){ actual_size=0;}
};
```

At which point I could fill up the vector to whatever size, reset it and reuse the same object without ever having to mess with the memory.  I'll be hogging memory, but I'd likely need almost that much memory each round anyway.  Annoyingly, I'd have to reimplement any STL vector routines that use size...

This seems like something that should be built into the STL somehow but looking at the docs, I can't figure out how to obtain this kind of behavior.

*EDIT:* Time penalty of push_back after clear.  Following the comments, I tried out `clear()`.  It does do what I want, except that I need to reallocate the memory (with almost as much time cost as the first time.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>

int main(){
int N=10000000;
std::vector<int> v;
auto start = std::clock();
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    v.push_back(rand());
auto t1 = std::clock();
std::cout << "push_back time: " << (t1 - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

v.clear();
start = std::clock();
std::cout << "clear time: " << (start - t1) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    v.push_back(rand());
t1 = std::clock();
std::cout << "push_back after clear time: " << (t1 - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

v.resize(0);
start = std::clock();
std::cout << "resize(0) time: " << (start - t1) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    v.push_back(rand());
t1 = std::clock();
std::cout << "push_back after resize(0) time: " << (t1 - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    v[i] = rand();
start = std::clock();
std::cout << "in_place time: " << (start - t1) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

assert(v.size() == N);
return 0;
}
```

On my run-of-the-mill Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz, I get:

```
push_back time:                 526.776 ms
clear time:                       0.121 ms
push_back after clear time:     445.08 ms
resize(0) time:                   0.034 ms
push_back after resize(0) time: 445.136 ms
in_place time:                  160.944 ms
```

Lesson 1, `clear()` and `resize(0)` are blazingly fast for ints, no question.  Lesson 2, pushing back after `clear()` takes almost as much time as pushing back in a virgin vector while in place assignment (which I was aiming for with my `reusable_vec` above) is 3x faster.

compiled with `-O2`:

```
push_back time:                 226.505 ms
clear time:                       0.117 ms
push_back after clear time:     145.651 ms
resize(0) time:                   0.034 ms
push_back after resize(0) time: 145.561 ms
in_place time:                  127.776 ms
```

Lesson 0, always compile with optimization! `resize(0)` and `clear()` are about the same.  However, the second round of `push_back`s is only 14% slower than in-place which is good enough for me.

Comment: Just call `clear()` and use it again.

Comment: What @chris said. Vector implementations usually keep their memory even when you make them smaller, you have to go to some trouble to get them to release it.

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear , clear is linear in the size of the container.  For a large vector being reset frequently, that adds a substantial cost.

Comment: "Linear in the size of the container" is simply because the destructor is called for each object erased. If your objects have trivial destructors you'll never notice it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, actually it is enough to call shrink_to_fit() function to release vector memory.

Comment: @user3564091, It's arguably more trouble than `clear()` since you might not realize that `clear` doesn't necessarily reduce the capacity, but I think Mark was talking in the context of pre-C++11, where `shrink_to_fit` did not yet exist and the convention was to do `std::vector<…>().swap(vec);`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, @chris, I'm seeing a 3x penalty using `clear()` then `push_back()` vs an in-place type solution.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can write an allocator that does this to extend `std::vector` to use your memory requirements.

Comment: You could also try `v.resize(0)` instead of `v.clear()`

Comment: BTW what optimizations are in effect for those times?  Also, `push_back()` has more work to do than `operator[]`, since it has to update the size and check whether the capacity is exceeded.  (I don't see why it should be any more expensive than your wrapper, though)

Comment: Right, forgot `-O2` posting new results now.

Comment: `push_back` is supposed to be very low overhead, although compared to indexing into an array of `int` it might be significant. You might try `size_t old_size=v.size(); v.clear(); v.reserve(old_size);` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Your last edit, with optimizations enabled, is about the level of overhead I'd expect to see with `push_back`. No telling why the unoptimized version was so slow.

Comment: Or inspect `capacity()` after `resize(0)` to make sure it hasn't freed the memory.  But it looks to me that with optimization the performance is now as desired.